# Reading in each data member of an unspecified struct from XML

Tags: c++

I have some structs with varying types and amounts of data members:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
}

struct Bar
{
    std::string a;
    int b;
}

struct Baz
{
    char a;
}
```

I want to fill these data members with values contained in an external file. Is there a general solution such that if I later add a new struct with different data members, I won't have to alter my code that's reading in the data? I'd prefer to keep any functionality independent of these structs, but my best idea at the moment is a polymorphic solution where each struct has a static method responsible for reading in its data.

Comment: You can't use a static member as `this` would be unavailable. I've been using XML for a long time, it works great with read and write members. I have examples [here](https://github.com/lakeweb/ECAD) using [PUGI-xml](https://pugixml.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ as of now doesn't have a way to reflect the content of a struct. This means that there is no truly generic way to read into any given struct (neither by name nor by index). However you might create some kind of meta-description which might result in less overhead than to rewrite the XML deserialization for each structure.

Such a meta-description could look like (requires C++17):

```
enum FieldType { String, Int, Float, Char };

struct AbstractField
{
    FieldType const type;
    const char * const name;
    AbstractField(FieldType type, const char *name) : type(type), name(name) {}
    virtual ~AbstractField() {}
    virtual bool setValue(std::any & dest, const std::any & value) const = 0;
}

template <typename Struct, typename Type>
struct Field : public AbstractField
{
    Type Struct::*const fieldPtr;
    Field(FieldType type, const char *name, Type Struct::*fieldPtr)
        : AbstractField(type, name), fieldPtr(fieldPtr)
    {}
    bool setValue(std::any & dest, const std::any & value) const override
    {
        Struct *realDest = std::any_cast<Struct>(& dest);
        const Type *realValue = std::any_cast<Type>(& value);
        if (realDest != nullptr && realValue != nullptr) {
            realDest->*fieldPtr = *realValue;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

// The following has to be redone for each structure
static const std::vector<const AbstractField *> metaFoo = {
    new Field<Foo, int>(Int, "a", & Foo::a)),
    new Field<Foo, float>(Float, "b", & Foo::b)),
    new Field<Foo, char>(Char, "c", & Foo:c))
};
```

There could be added some extra logic to get this even fancier (type_id instead of the enum, templated functions that only take the name and the member pointer to create the `Field` instance, abstract factories for the individual structs, etc).

The reader could then set a value in the structure like this

```
std::any parseValue(const std::string & value, FieldType type);

bool setField(std::any &dest, const std::vector<const AbstractField*> &meta,
              const std::string & fieldName, const std::string & value)
{
    for (auto field : meta) {
        if (field->name == fieldName) {
            std::any value = parseValue(value, field->type);
            return field->setValue(dest, value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When combined with abstract factories for the structs (similar to what I've done for the fields) this allows to instanciate a whole tree of structures just from the meta-description.